# Bootstrap: scrollspy doesn't work after I've added smooth scrolling

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, smooth-scrolling, scrollspy

I'm building a site using Twitter Bootstrap, and I got the scrollspy to work, using the below javascript:

```
$('body').scrollspy({ target: '.navbar' })
```

But it stopped working for me, after I add the script to enable smooth scrolling:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  // navigation click actions 
  $('.scroll-link').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var sectionID = $(this).attr("data-id");
    scrollToID('#' + sectionID, 750);
  });
  // scroll to top action
  $('.scroll-top').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');     
  });
  // mobile nav toggle
  $('.nav-toggle').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1').toggleClass("open");
  });
});
// scroll function
function scrollToID(id, speed){
  var offSet = 70;
  var targetOffset = $(id).offset().top - offSet;
  var mainNav = $('#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1');
  $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:targetOffset}, speed);
  if (mainNav.hasClass("open")) {
    mainNav.css("height", "1px").removeClass("in").addClass("collapse");
    mainNav.removeClass("open");
  }
}
if (typeof console === "undefined") {
    console = {
        log: function() { }
    };
}
</script>
```

I'm thinking I must have added the scrollspy in an incorrect position. I have very little knowledge of javascript. If someone can point me the way to inserting it in the correct order/space/line, that would be great!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use a third party plugin such as jquery.localScroll (which relies on jquery.scrollTo). It provides great smooth scrolling and is easy to implement. A lot easier than reimplementing the wheel.

https://github.com/flesler/jquery.localScroll

Comment: Thanks Troy. Maybe I'm reading the localScroll wrong. But I not only need it to have smooth scrolling, I need my main nav links (which is in fixed position), to be highlighted, when the page is scrolled to.  Right now, I can get either smooth scrolling, or scrollspy to work. But I can't combine them so that both works. Is it possible to combine those 2 scripts in javascript? I'm just starting out and am quite useless when it comes to javascript/jquery. Any further help will be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I have a few sites where I use scroll spy and localScroll together, and have had no conflicts.  I get both the highlighting of the static nav bar, and smooth scrolling when people click on the navbar links.  You can also target localScroll to links that are only in part of the document (i.e. your navbar).  Just make sure you include jquery.scrollTo before jquery.LocalScroll.